# Uppercase URL in requests returns "Name does not resolve"

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I'd like to GET data from an URL with uppercase characters. The URL is based on a docker hostname. requests always returns `Name does not resolve` as it lowers the URL.

The URL is `http://gateway.Niedersachsen/api/bundeslaender`.

`ping gateway.Niedersachsen` works but `ping gateway.niedersachsen` does not.

My Python requests code:

```py
url = f'http://gateway.Niedersachsen/api/wfs/insertGeometry'
r = requests.get(url)
```

The following error occurs:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='gateway.niedersachsen', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/wfs/insertGeometry (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5f5eb5a3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve'))
```

My versions:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3

> requests.__version__
'2.21.0'
```

Comment: How about replace `gateway.Niedersachsen` by its IP?

Comment: That's no option due to scaling of the gateway service. Multiple services result in multiple IPs 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3986/?include_text=1) Section 6.2.2.1 says about URIs:

> [...] the scheme and **host** are **case-insensitive** and therefore **should be normalized to lowercase** [...].

IMHO, your name resolution behaves incorrectly and there seems to be an open [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21169) related to case-sensitivity for Docker's networking, which I assume is in use here.

`requests`, resp. `urllib3`, honors the RFC recommendation, at least for HTTP scheme connections. As far as `requests` is concerned, there seem to be four relevant places where hostnames are converted to lowercase.

1. `urllib3`'s utility class [`Url`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/util/url.py#L35) which comes into play when `requests`' `PreparedRequest` instance executes the [`prepare_url`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L379) method.
2. the [`_default_key_normalizer`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L84) function that is called by the [`PoolManager`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L241) via the [`key_fn_by_scheme`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L114) mapping
3. in case your hostname contains non-ASCII characters, it is also [passed through](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L346) IDNA encoding, but this is not the case in your example.
4. `urllib3` version 1.22 also had a `lower()` call on the host name in the [`ConnectionPool`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/1.22/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L71) base class initializer. This normalization has been moved to the [`_ipv6_host`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L898) function as of version 1.23 apparently.

Using monkeypatching I seem to have been able to coerce `requests`, resp. `urllib3`, into leaving the host name portion of the URL untouched:

```
import functools
import urllib3

def _custom_key_normalizer(key_class, request_context):
    # basically a 1:1 copy of urllib3.poolmanager._default_key_normalizer
    # commenting out 
    # https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L84
    #context['host'] = context['host'].lower()

class ConnectionPool(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port=None):
        # complete copy of urllib3.connectionpool.ConnectionPool base class
        # I needed this due to my urllib3 version 1.22. 
        # If you have urllib3 >= 1.23 this is not necessary
        # remove the .lower() from 
        # https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/1.22/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L71
        self.host = urllib3.connectionpool._ipv6_host(host)

urllib3.util.url.NORMALIZABLE_SCHEMES = (None,)
# This is needed for urllib3 >= 1.23. The connectionpool module imports
# NORMALIZABLE_SCHEMES before we can patch it, so we have to explicitly patch it again
urllib3.connectionpool.NORMALIZABLE_SCHEMES = (None,)
urllib3.poolmanager.key_fn_by_scheme['http'] = functools.partial(_custom_key_normalizer, 
                                                                 urllib3.poolmanager.PoolKey)
# just for urllib3 < 1.23
urllib3.connectionpool.ConnectionPool = ConnectionPool

# do not use anything that would import urllib3 before this point    
import requests
url = f'http://gateway.Niedersachsen/api/wfs/insertGeometry'
r = requests.get(url)
```

I assume success by the fact that my error message, displaying the host used in the connection pool, still uses the initial capitalization:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='gateway.Niedersachsen', port=80): [...]
```

**Note:**
There might be an even easier method by using `urllib3` directly; I haven't looked into this.
Also, if someone knows a more straight forward way of preserving host capitalization using `requests`, *please* let me know.

Comment: Looks good, but I was not able to get this running. I'm using `urllib3` version 1.24.1 and therefore omitted some of your code. I used usual and [prepared requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) to debug and my prepped request had the correct (uppercase) URL. The actual request however failed with the same initial error. Don't know whats wrong...

Comment: @Felix I missed that the normalization in the `ConnectionPool` base class has been _moved_, not _removed_, in `urllib3` version 1.23. You need to patch `NORMALIZABLE_SCHEMES` on the level of the `connectionpool` module as well: `urllib3.connectionpool.NORMALIZABLE_SCHEMES = (None,)`. I updated my answer.