# Python requests get url with uppercase letter

Tags: python, url, python-requests

i have an url provided by pihole API that has an uppercase letter in it, and i am trying to get url contents with the requests in python, here's the code:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('http://localhost/admin/api.php?topClients')
rstats = json.loads(r.text)

print(json.dumps(rstats))
```

apparently it seems that all urls are converted to lowercase by `urllib`, hence the part of the url `api.php?topClients` becomes `api.php?topclients` and the result is an empty array since pihole only provides data if the url has `Clients` part in uppercase.

Is there a way to properly get the contents of that url please?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607769/uppercase-url-in-requests-returns-name-does-not-resolve